# While doing decryption using crypto, getting bad decrypt error using Node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I am storing information in the database in an encrypted format. When I am retrieving it from the database and applying decrypt on it, I am getting error like "bad decrypt"

Here is my code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

function encrypt(text) {
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", Buffer.from(key), iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
  encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
  return { iv: iv.toString("hex"), encryptedData: encrypted.toString("hex") };
}

function decrypt(text) {
  let iv = Buffer.from(text.iv, "hex");
  let encryptedText = Buffer.from(text.encryptedData, "hex");
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", Buffer.from(key), iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
  return decrypted.toString();
}

/********** following is the api **************/
exports.viewTrade = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("viewTrade api ", req.query);
  let maindData = [];
  var hw = {
    iv: "fc4ca9a17d97d7a7772449cfea3a99b8",
    encryptedData: "e966509fd17785b4fe8304ef2f531806",
  };
  console.log(decrypt(hw));

  const tradeList = await trade.find({
    createdBy: req.query.id,
  });

  if (tradeList.length) {
    for (tradeInfo of tradeList) {
      // let nameInfo = tradeInfo.name;
      // // let value = decrypt(nameInfo);
      // console.log("name info.. ", nameInfo);
      // // console.log("value.. ", value);
    }
  }
};
```

By calling the above API, it is throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try out your code I'm getting a error like this: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt.

This probably means that the key used to decrypt is not the same as the encryption key.

I suspect this is because the code above re-creates the key on each run.

I would suggest you use a fixed key, maybe coming from an environment variable, or secure secrets store. To test this you can just initialize your key like so:

```
const key = Buffer.from("232f150296ffd446fc0b39fa32d1c1d42c2e232ccd3203df729b7f3c3c63a5da2", "hex");
```

Then encrypt a message and see that it will decrypt correctly like so:

```
const encrypted = encrypt("We love Stack Overflow");
const decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);

console.log("encrypted data:", encrypted);
console.log("decrypted data:", decrypted);
```

You'll notice that if you copy the encrypted data from one run of the program to the next, it should work with a fixed key, but give you the bad_decrypt error if you generate the key on each run.

Key Generation code:

```
 const key = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
```

Comment: Terry Lennox, thank you for the quick answer. By using the key you mentioned, I am getting a proper value. But I have questions. 1. I made a log of key for both encryption and decryption. In encryption, the key is generating the same but in decryption, it is showing different. Why? I define key globally, so why it was taking different key?
2. How did you generate that key? Is there any way?

Comment: Hmmm.. to point 1. I'm not quite sure why the key would be different, it might be that you ran the program twice, hence the key was regenerated. 2. To generate the key I ran the code: const key = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"); I would also be careful about logging the key to any log file, you have the same security problem with logging passwords, maybe just log part of the key!

Comment: Okay!! when I am generating the key using **const key = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");** and doing encryption, it is showing invalid key length.. Do I need to show you code?

Comment: Oh dear, my apologies, I wasn't fully clear about the key generation and usage. To generate the key, use const key = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"); Then to use it: const key = Buffer.from(<key in hex>, "hex");

Comment: Okay!! It's done... It is giving me the proper value(encryption and decryption) as I want. Thank you so so much Terry. :) You saved my day and I will accept this answer as the correct answer. Thanks a tone again.. :)

Comment: No problem, I'm very glad to help. Good luck with the project!

Comment: Terry, I am getting again that error bad decrypt. I have use rypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"). Is there something limit on it?

Comment: We just need to make sure that when we pass the key to the encrypt() function, that the key is a buffer, and likewise in decrypt(). So if the key is a hex string, this will cause issues. You could, if you like, store the key as a hex string. In which case, replace the Buffer.from(key) to Buffer.from(key, "hex") in both the encrypt and decrypt functions.